# Create stored procedure (int[] as param) which deletes existing records in table when there is no match in int array

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

ex: if i have sent 1,2,3 params to stored procedure with idxyz, then table has 1,2,3,4,5 ids then 4,5 should be deleted from table.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_array_input(INT[]) RETURNS SETOF ids AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
        in_clause ALIAS FOR $1;
        clause  TEXT;
        rec     RECORD;
BEGIN
        FOR rec IN SELECT id FROM ids WHERE id = ANY(in_clause)

        LOOP
                RETURN NEXT rec;
        END LOOP;
        -- final return
        RETURN;
END
$BODY$ language plpgsql;

ex: SELECT * FROM example_array_input('{1,2,4,5,6}'::INT[]);
```

if existing table has 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. then it should delete 7,8,9 from that table since these are not there in the input array

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DELETE` statement like this for your purpose.

```
DELETE FROM ids   
where id NOT IN ( select UNNEST('{1,2,4,5,6}'::INT[]) ) ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ed260/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sql function that returns the deleted ids:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_array_input(in_clause INT[]) RETURNS SETOF ids
  language sql
AS  
$SQL$
  DELETE
    FROM ids
    WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT unnest(in_clause) )
  RETURNING id;
$SQL$;
```

You can see a running example in http://rextester.com/PFG55537

In a 1 to 10 table running

```
SELECT * FROM example_array_input('{1,2,4,5,6}'::INT[]);
```

you obtain:
[image: result]